# python selenium - can't scrape further at some specific height in dynamic page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time 


def main():
    # options
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # headless
    options.add_argument('headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    url = 'https://channels.vlive.tv/FE123/home'
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:

        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height 
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height > 82590:#== last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
    print(last_height, 'finished scrolling')

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    html = driver.page_source
    print(html)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code opens a headless chrome and navigates to url, and scrolls down to load dynamic contents to the new_height > 82590 and copies html.

The problem is when I scroll a bit more, like new_height > 82591, it crashes at 'html = driver.page_source' and doesn't print html. The page can be scrolled down to over 120000+. And the other page which can be scrolled down more than 120000 was good with this code.

When it crashes I got the message filled with a bunch of html in one line, not printed from print(html), and the following.

```
(Session info: headless chrome=80.0.3987.122)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know what happens between the height 82590 and 82591, but something is wrong in there...

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace? Did you try without headless mode ?

Comment: @Sureshmani Sorry, I don't understand what stack trace is. But the result I've got is pretty much the same as I described in the post except the one line html thing is too long to put it in here. And yes, I tried without headless mode and got the same result.

Comment: @user642721 This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB scrolling down to the bottom, scrapping html, and getting all text in it. i just want to do some data analysis on it. if you can get full html without scrolling down, please let me know how to do that.